# How to unit test a Grails After filter that updates the Model

Tags: grails, grails-filters

**How do I test a Grails filter which updates the model?**

**How do I inspect the model updated by a filter within a unit test?**

I'm using Grails 2.3.4

Using the [Grails Unit Testing guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingFilters)

I have created a filter test:

```
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
@TestFor(MyController)
@Mock(MyFilters)
class MyFiltersTest {
  @Test
  void myFilterAddsAModelEntry(){
     def model
     withFilters(action:"index"){
       model=controller.index()
     }

     println "model in test: $model"

     assert model.filterObject == "hello world"
  } 
}
```

However, the test fails as the returned model does not include the filterObject, even though the filters are called.

With the following Controller:

```
class MyController {
  def index(){
    println "MyController.index() called"
    // return empty model
    [:]
}
```

and Filter:

```
class MyFilters {
  def filters = {
    all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
      before = {
        println "before filter called"
      }
      after {Map model ->
        println "after filter called"
        model.filterObject="hello world"
        println "filtered model: $model"
        model
      }
      afterView = { Exception e -> }
    }
  }
}
```

The test generates the following output:

```
before filter called...
MyController.index() called...
after filter called
filtered model: [filterObject:hello world]
model in test: [:]
```

Comment: there are multiple issues: First `model=controller.index()` is called before the `after` filter. Second: I would expect the changed model in the `model` property of the test as in a normal controller tests (you do not need to create it). But that does not work because `withFilter` "copies" the model before passing it to the filter. So you will never get at the modified model. Looks broken to me...

Comment: @MartinHauner thanks for your comment.  I came to the same conclusion after some further investigation.  I shall look into creating a bug ticket and post a suggested solution.